# Как выбрать все столбцы таблицы используя PHQL?

Tags: sql, phalcon

Есть вот такой  запрос:

```
$data = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("
    SELECT 
         Aincrad\Models\Inventory.*,
         Aincrad\Models\Items.name, 
         Aincrad\Models\Items.description,
         Aincrad\Models\Items.path_img,
         Aincrad\Models\Items.lvl, 
         Aincrad\Models\Items.price
    FROM Aincrad\Models\Inventory 
    JOIN  Aincrad\Models\Items
    ON Aincrad\Models\Inventory.id_item = Aincrad\Models\Items.id 
    WHERE  Aincrad\Models\Inventory.id_user = :id_user: AND Aincrad\Models\Inventory.id = :id_item: 
    LIMIT 1
 ", array(
                "id_item" => $idItems,
                "id_user" => $auth['id']
            ));
```

Проблема в том что я не могу получить данные всех столбцов  Aincrad\Models\Inventory.* . 
Подскажите пожалуйста  что я не так делаю.
Можно конечно перечислить все столбцы таблицы inventory  вручную, но это неудобно так как со временем количество столбцов будет расти.

```
SELECT  Aincrad\Models\Inventory.id,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.id_user,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.id_item,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.str,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.dex,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.sta,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.int,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.min_attack,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.max_attack,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.defense,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.critical_chance,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.critical_damage,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.strength,
    Aincrad\Models\Inventory.created_at,
    Aincrad\Models\Items.name, 
    Aincrad\Models\Items.description,
    Aincrad\Models\Items.path_img,
    Aincrad\Models\Items.lvl, 
    Aincrad\Models\Items.price
       FROM Aincrad\Models\Inventory 
       JOIN  Aincrad\Models\Items
       ON Aincrad\Models\Inventory.id_item = Aincrad\Models\Items.id 
       WHERE  Aincrad\Models\Inventory.id_user = :id_user: AND Aincrad\Models\Inventory.id = :id_item: 
    LIMIT 1
```

(Так хотя бы  работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что когда вы пишите:

```
 Aincrad\Models\Inventory.*
```

Phalcon возвращает Вам данные которые отображены на модель Aincrad\Models\Inventory и следовательно возвращается она. Сделайте к данной модели алиас:

```
$data = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("
    SELECT 
         Inventory.*,
         Aincrad\Models\Items.name, 
         Aincrad\Models\Items.description,
         Aincrad\Models\Items.path_img,
         Aincrad\Models\Items.lvl, 
         Aincrad\Models\Items.price
    FROM Aincrad\Models\Inventory Inventory
    JOIN  Aincrad\Models\Items
    ON Inventory.id_item = Aincrad\Models\Items.id 
    WHERE  Inventory.id_user = :id_user: AND Inventory.id = :id_item: 
    LIMIT 1
 ", array(
                "id_item" => $idItems,
                "id_user" => $auth['id']
            ));
```

И при выводе обращайтесь к классу и его публичным свойствам или методам.

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
   echo $item->Inventory->id_user;
}
```

Только если свойства модели публичные и не скрыты модификатором protected/public.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.